# Rearranging the elements of array with specific positions

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, pointers

User has to make an array from any amount of numbers and I need to rearrange the array, so that the elements from EVEN places would move to the start of an array and from UNEVEN places to the end. For example `A=[1,2,3,4,5,6]` would turn into `B=[2,4,6,1,3,5]`. Also I need to use **POINTERS**.... I am very bad at pointers, so help would be very much appreciated.

This is as far as I got myself. I am not using pointers here though, because I don't know how to.. :(

```
void switcharoo(int a, int b[]){
    int temp[a], j=0;
    for(int i=1;i<a;i+=2){
        temp[j] = b[i];
        j++;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<a;i+=2){
        temp[j] = b[i];
        j++;
    }
    b = temp;
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How to write this function with POINTERS. I wrote it without them, but I need to write it WITH them.

Comment: You wrote a function with a lot of data assignments. What is unexpected? Did the program crash? Your **are** **using** pointers like `b` and `temp`. Did you expect anything when you change the pointer `b` immediately before return?

Comment: The program is working, but the task requires to use the pointers with * symbol. :(

Comment: So it's homework.

Comment: `int temp[a]` is not valid C++.VLA is an extension.

Comment: `b[i]` can be replaced by `*(b + i)` to use pointer.

Comment: So you can't help me even with an explanation? I wrote the full code, except I am stuck at this part, because I don't really understand pointers using * @harper

Comment: @Jarod42 thank you!

Comment: `int b[]` as formal paramter is identical with `int *b`. `temp[j]` is identical with `*(temp+j)`. Your request "use more stars in the source code" can be fullfilled with such replacement. But "use more stars" isn't sensible. Probably the replacement examples help. --- If you want to make your code change the data array: you have to write to `b[index]` to actually modify the array. Modifying the pointer `b` is not sufficient.

Comment: Okay, the code isn't working properly aswell... Uh. I need to think. I understand the pointers now, thank you for that. Just need to fix the code now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oups, you have still to improve your C++ knowledge...

- `int temp[a]` is not valid C++ as you have been told in comment - Variable Length Arrays are a C feature
- `b` is passed as a pointer (an arrays decays to a pointer to its first element when passed to a function). When you write `b=temp;` at the end of you function, you only change a local copy... which immediately goes out of scope: in short the current code is just a no-op.
- array indices start at 0

If you want to train in using pointers, you could do something like that:

```
void switcharoo(int a, int b[]) {
    int *even = new int[a];  // allocate an array of same size
    int *odd = even + a / 2;  // point at the mid array element
    for (int i = 0; i<a - 1; i += 2) {
        *odd++ = b[i];        // odd elements in high part
        *even++ = b[i + 1];   // even in low part
    }
    if (0 != a % 2) { // one odd element remains
        *odd++ = b[a - 1];
    }
    even = odd - a;     // make even point again to start of allocated array
    odd = even;         // store a copy
    for (int i = 0; i<a; i++) { // copy back in original array
        b[i] = *even++;
    }
    delete[] odd;       // and delete the allocated array
}
```